# Memory footprint of splitOn?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a file indexing program that should read thousands of text file lines as records and finally group those records by fingerprint. It uses `Data.List.Split.splitOn` to split the lines at tabs and retrieve the record fields. The program consumes 10-20 GB of memory.

Probably there is not much I can do to reduce that huge memory footprint, but I cannot explain why a function like `splitOn` (`breakDelim`) can consume that much memory:

```
    Mon Dec  9 21:07 2019 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       group +RTS -p -RTS file1 file2 -o 2 -h

    total time  =        7.40 secs   (7399 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 14,324,828,696 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE                          MODULE                    SRC                                                %time %alloc

fileToPairs.linesIncludingEmptyLines ImageFileRecordParser     ImageFileRecordParser.hs:35:7-47                    25.0   33.8
breakDelim                           Data.List.Split.Internals src/Data/List/Split/Internals.hs:(151,1)-(156,36)   24.9   39.3
sortAndGroup                         Aggregations              Aggregations.hs:6:1-85                              12.9    1.7
fileToPairs                          ImageFileRecordParser     ImageFileRecordParser.hs:(33,1)-(42,14)              8.2   10.7
matchDelim                           Data.List.Split.Internals src/Data/List/Split/Internals.hs:(73,1)-(77,23)      7.4    0.4
onSublist                            Data.List.Split.Internals src/Data/List/Split/Internals.hs:278:1-72            3.6    0.0
toHashesView                         ImageFileRecordStatistics ImageFileRecordStatistics.hs:(48,1)-(51,24)          3.0    6.3
main                                 Main                      group.hs:(47,1)-(89,54)                              2.9    0.4
numberOfUnique                       ImageFileRecord           ImageFileRecord.hs:37:1-40                           1.6    0.1
toHashesView.sortedLines             ImageFileRecordStatistics ImageFileRecordStatistics.hs:50:7-30                 1.4    0.1
imageFileRecordFromFields            ImageFileRecordParser     ImageFileRecordParser.hs:(11,1)-(30,5)               1.1    0.3
toHashView                           ImageFileRecord           ImageFileRecord.hs:(67,1)-(69,23)                    0.7    1.7
```

Or is type `[Char]` too memory inefficient (compared to `Text`), causing `splitOn` to take that much memory?

UPDATE 1 (`+RTS -s` suggestion of user HTNW)

```
  23,446,268,504 bytes allocated in the heap
  10,753,363,408 bytes copied during GC
   1,456,588,656 bytes maximum residency (22 sample(s))
      29,282,936 bytes maximum slop
            3620 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     45646 colls,     0 par    4.055s   4.059s     0.0001s    0.0013s
  Gen  1        22 colls,     0 par    4.034s   4.035s     0.1834s    1.1491s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    7.477s  (  7.475s elapsed)
  GC      time    8.089s  (  8.094s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.114s  (  0.114s elapsed)
  Total   time   15.687s  ( 15.683s elapsed)

  %GC     time      51.6%  (51.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,135,625,407 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  48.4% of total user, 48.4% of total elapsed
```

The processed text files are smaller than usual (UTF-8 encoded, 37 MB). But still 3 GB of memory are used.

UPDATE 2 (critical part of the code)

Explanation: `fileToPairs` processes a text file. It returns a list of key-value pairs (key: fingerprint of record, value: record).

```
sortAndGroup associations = Map.fromListWith (++) [(k, [v]) | (k, v) <- associations]

main = do
  CommandLineArguments{..} <- cmdArgs $ CommandLineArguments {
    ignored_paths_file = def &= typFile,
    files = def &= typ "FILES" &= args,
    number_of_occurrences = def &= name "o",
    minimum_number_of_occurrences = def &= name "l",
    maximum_number_of_occurrences = def &= name "u",
    number_of_hashes = def &= name "n",
    having_record_errors = def &= name "e",
    hashes = def
  }
    &= summary "Group image/video files"
    &= program "group"

  let ignoredPathsFilenameMaybe = ignored_paths_file
  let filenames = files
  let hashesMaybe = hashes

  ignoredPaths <- case ignoredPathsFilenameMaybe of
    Just ignoredPathsFilename -> ioToLines (readFile ignoredPathsFilename)
    _ -> return []

  recordPairs <- mapM (fileToPairs ignoredPaths) filenames

  let allRecordPairs = concat recordPairs
  let groupMap = sortAndGroup allRecordPairs
  let statisticsPairs = map toPair (Map.toList groupMap) where toPair item = (fst item, imageFileRecordStatisticsFromRecords . snd $ item)

  let filterArguments = FilterArguments {
    numberOfOccurrencesMaybe = number_of_occurrences,
    minimumNumberOfOccurrencesMaybe = minimum_number_of_occurrences,
    maximumNumberOfOccurrencesMaybe = maximum_number_of_occurrences,
    numberOfHashesMaybe = number_of_hashes,
    havingRecordErrorsMaybe = having_record_errors
  }
  let filteredPairs = filterImageRecords filterArguments statisticsPairs

  let filteredMap = Map.fromList filteredPairs
  case hashesMaybe of
        Just True -> mapM_ putStrLn (map toHashesView (map snd filteredPairs))
        _ -> Char8.putStrLn (encodePretty filteredMap)
```

Comment: `[Char]` is not efficient, and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: There are good and bad data structures along with good and bad algorithms... It all depends on your approach.

Comment: On a 64 bit machine, `[Char]` uses at least 24 bytes *per character!* Use `Data.Text`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `Data.Text`. But please also answer my question about `splitOn`.

Comment: @Redu Currently my approach is as simple as possible: I am putting all records into list and create a map from that list. What would you recommend? But before trying a new approach I need to understand why the `splitOn` function seems to be the most memory-hungry function.

Comment: `total alloc` is not the memory used. It's good to keep that down, but the actual maximum memory is given by `+RTS -s` "maximum residency". Total allocations is usually a measure of "work," being mostly temporary objects. Anyway, seeing the actual code is a necessity here. Also, careless/automatic profiling can block significant optimizations. `+RTS -s` works without profiling, check that (after recompiling with profiling off, ofc). 100,000 lines at 1,000 chars each is still <3GB in a NF `[Char]`, according to @luqui, that may or may not signify something's up.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the critical part of the code, you believe being memory hungry. That way it would also help the community to stay away from such approaches if that's the case. Once you have a solid question, I am sure someone will point out the right direction with a solid answer.

Comment: @luqui, yes, and that's for ASCII or so; anything else is 40 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

As I'm sure you're aware, there's not really enough information here for us to help you make your program more efficient.  It might be worth posting some (complete, self-contained) code on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for that.

However, I think I can answer your specific question about why `splitOn` allocates so much memory.  In fact, there's nothing particularly special about `splitOn` or how it's been implemented.  Many straightforward Haskell functions will allocate lots of memory, and this in itself doesn't indicate that they've been poorly written or are running inefficiently.  In particular, `splitOn`'s memory usage seems similar to other straightforward approaches to splitting a string based on delimiters.

The first thing to understand is that GHC compiled code works differently than other compiled code you're likely to have seen.  If you know a lot of C and understand stack frames and heap allocation, or if you've studied some JVM implementations, you might reasonably expect that some of that understanding would translate to GHC executables, but you'd be mostly wrong.

A GHC program is more or less an engine for allocating heap objects, and -- with a few exceptions -- that's all it really does.  Nearly every argument passed to a function or constructor (as well as the constructor application itself) allocates a heap object of at least 16 bytes, and often more.  Take a simple function like:

```
fact :: Int -> Int
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

With optimization turned off, it compiles to the following so-called "STG" form (simplified from the actual `-O0 -ddump-stg` output):

```
fact = \n -> case n of I# n' -> case n' of
  0# -> I# 1#
  _ -> let sat1 = let sat2 = let one = I#! 1# in n-one
                  in fact sat2;
       in n*sat1
```

Everywhere you see a `let`, that's a heap allocation (16+ bytes), and there are presumably more hidden in the `(-)` and `(*)` calls.  Compiling and running this program with:

```
main = print $ fact 1000000
```

gives:

```
 113,343,544 bytes allocated in the heap
  44,309,000 bytes copied during GC
  25,059,648 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
      29,152 bytes maximum slop
          23 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

meaning that each iteration allocates over a hundred bytes on the heap, though it's literally just performing a comparison, a subtraction, a multiplication, and a recursive call,

This is what @HTNW meant in saying that total allocation in a GHC program is a measure of "work".  A GHC program that isn't allocating probably isn't doing anything (again, with some rare exceptions), and a typical GHC program that *is* doing something will usually allocate at a relatively constant rate of several gigabytes per second when it's not garbage collecting.  So, total allocation has more to do with total runtime than anything else, and it isn't a particularly good metric for assessing code efficiency.  Maximum residency is also a poor measure of overall efficiency, though it can be helpful for assessing whether or not you have a space leak, if you find that it tends to grow linearly (or worse) with the size of the input where you expect the program should run in constant memory regardless of input size.

For most programs, the most important true *efficiency* metric in the `+RTS -s` output is probably the "productivity" rate at the bottom -- it's the amount of time the program spends *not* garbage collecting.  And, admittedly, your program's productivity of 48% is pretty bad, which probably means that it is, technically speaking, allocating too much memory, but it's probably only allocating two or three times the amount it should be, so, at a guess, maybe it should "only" be allocating around 7-8 Gigs instead of 23 Gigs for this workload (and, consequently, running for about 5 seconds instead of 15 seconds).

With that in mind, if you consider the following simple `breakDelim` implementation:

```
breakDelim :: String -> [String]
breakDelim str = case break (=='\t') str of
  (a,_:b) -> a : breakDelim b
  (a,[])  -> [a]
```

and use it like so in a simple tab-to-comma delimited file converter:

```
main = interact (unlines . map (intercalate "," . breakDelim) . lines)
```

Then, unoptimized and run on a file with 10000 lines of 1000 3-character fields each, it allocates a whopping 17 Gigs:

```
  17,227,289,776 bytes allocated in the heap
   2,807,297,584 bytes copied during GC
         127,416 bytes maximum residency (2391 sample(s))
          32,608 bytes maximum slop
               0 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

and profiling it places a lot of blame on `breakDelim`:

```
COST CENTRE MODULE    SRC                    %time %alloc

main        Main      Delim.hs:8:1-71         57.7   72.6
breakDelim  Main      Delim.hs:(4,1)-(6,16)   42.3   27.4
```

In this case, compiling with `-O2` doesn't make much difference.  The key efficiency metric, productivity, is only 46%.  All these results seem to be in line with what you're seeing in your program.

The `split` package has a lot going for it, but looking through the code, it's pretty clear that little effort has been made to make it particularly efficient or fast, so it's no surprise that `splitOn` performs no better than my quick-and-dirty custom `breakDelim` function.  And, as I said before, there's nothing special about `splitOn` that makes it unusually memory hungry -- my simple `breakDelim` has similar behavior.

With respect to inefficiencies of the `String` type, it can often be problematic.  But, it can also participate in optimizations like list fusion in ways that `Text` can't.  The utility above could be rewritten in simpler form as:

```
main = interact $ map (\c -> if c == '\t' then ',' else c)
```

which uses `String` but runs pretty fast (about a quarter as fast as a naive C `getchar`/`putchar` implementation) at 84% productivity, while allocating about 5 Gigs on the heap.

It's quite likely that if you just take your program and "convert it to `Text`", you'll find it's slower and more memory hungry than the original!  While `Text` has the potential to be *much* more efficient than `String`, it's a complicated package, and the way in which `Text` objects behave with respect to allocation when they're sliced and diced (as when you're chopping a big `Text` file up into little `Text` fields) makes it more difficult to get right.

So, some take-home lessons:

- Total allocation is a poor measure of efficiency.  Most well written GHC programs can and should allocate several gigabytes per second of runtime.
- Many innocuous Haskell functions will allocate lots of memory because of the way GHC compiled code works.  This isn't necessarily a sign that there's something wrong with the function.
- The `split` package provides a flexible framework for all manner of cool list splitting manipulations, but it was not designed with speed in mind, and it may not be the best method of processing a tab-delimited file.
- The `String` data type has a potential for terrible inefficiency, but isn't *always* inefficient, and `Text` is a complicated package that won't be a plug-in replacement to fix your `String` performance woes.

Most importantly:

- Unless your program is too slow for its intended purpose, its run-time statistics and the theoretical advantages of `Text` over `String` are largely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

How would you write a (more efficient than mine) program that groups records by one of its fields? I think it is a pretty common and simple task.

Comment: I'd probably start by looking at the `cassava` package for parsing delimited text.  It's built on top of the high-performance Attoparsec parser and has been designed with efficiency in mind.  It can parse records into `Vector`s of `Text` (or `Vector`s of `ByteString` or arbitrary algebraic data types) and should take care of most of the tricky allocation issues I mentioned above.

Comment: I simply replaced `splitOn` by `cassava` and now it eats only 4 Gigabytes of memory. That is still a lot but much better than before.